# Programa de encriptacion no me arroja resultados

Tags: python-3.x, algoritmos, base64, encriptación, lógica

Estoy haciendo un programa de encriptación de mensajes que permita encriptar mensajes con el método Vigenere, pero cuando ejecuto el código, no me arroja ningún resultado (cuando pongo `print(resultado)` lo arroja vacío, sin nada, pero sin error alguno). Dejo el código mas abajo tanto del `index.py` (que es el archivo desde donde el usuario podría seleccionar el método de encriptado, en este caso Vigenere) y el `vigenere.py` (que es el archivo con la lógica). Probé imprimir el resultado, así como poner `print()` en las listas donde se deberían guardar los mensajes tanto encriptados como desencriptados, pero nada arroja. Desde ya, muchísimas gracias y estoy abierto a cualquier consulta.

Index.py:

```
import base64

# import cesar

cmode = str(input("choose encription mode: "))
if cmode == "vigenere":
  exec(open("vigenere.py").read())
elif cmode == "cesar":
  exec(open("cesar.py").read())
else:
  print("Error, no ejecuta ninguno, cambiar exec?")
```

Vigenere.py

```
import base64

Text = str(input("enter text to encode: "))
private_key = str(input("enter key word: "))
mode = str(input("enter mode (e or d): "))
Result = str()


def Encode(key, message):
    enc = []

    for i in range(len(message)):
        # ciclo for para que recorra todo el mensaje a encriptar
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        # esto divide el rango del largo de key por i, y convirtiendo cada letra (para eso
        # el rango del largo, para que tome de a una letra) en un codigo diferente, en este
        # caso el ASCII
        enc.append(chr((ord(message[i]) + ord(key_c)) % 256))
        # esto agrega cada letra convertida a ASCII a la lista vacia [enc]
        print(enc)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc).encode()).decode()


# funcion que realiza la codificacion de los mensajes


def Decode(key, message):
    dec = []
    message = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message).decode()

    for i in range(len(message)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec.append(chr((256 + ord(message[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256))
        print(dec)
    return "".join(dec)


# funcion que realiza la decodificacion de los mensajes
# misma logica que la funcion anterior, solo que al reves


def Mode():
    if mode == "e":
        Result.set(Encode(private_key.get(), Text.get()))
    elif mode == "d":
        Result.set(Decode(private_key.get(), Text.get()))
    else:
        Result.set("Invalid Mode")


# funcion que le permite al usuario cambiar entre codificacion y decodificacion


def Reset():
    Text.set("")
    private_key.set("")
    mode.set("")
    Result.set("")


# funcion para resetear todo el programa y arrancar desde 0
# no tira resultados (en realidad, tira blanco, si no tirase fallaria)
```

Comment: Cargar un módulo python mediante `open().read()` para después ejecutarlo mediante `exec()` es una de las cosas más retorcidas que he visto hasta ahora :-) La forma de cargar un módulo obviamente es `import modulo`, eso ya lo ejecuta. Aunque en realidad sería más correcto que esos módulos se limitaran a declarar las clases que cifran y no a pedir la entrada de texto. Esa parte debería hacerla el programa principal y después llamar a `vigenere.Encode()` o `cesar.Encode()`, o lo que corresponda.

Comment: Mil gracias @abulafia me salvas las papas siempre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código en sí está bastante cifrado... ;D

**Primero tienes que llamar a la función "Mode", tal que así:**

```
def Mode():
    if mode == "e":
        Result = Encode(private_key, Text)
    elif mode == "d":
        Result = Decode(private_key, Text())
    else:
        Result = "Invalid Mode"

Mode()
```

Porque la magia de Python no da para estas cosas.

**Y también tienes que sustiruir o quitar los métodos "set" y "get" por "=" según convenga.**

```
Result = Encode(private_key, Text)
```

**Y este es el resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No solo te llevas el like por la respuesta, sino tambien por el chiste del principio. Gracias Francisco por tu ayuda.

Comment: @MatiasRico Si quieres apoyar aun más a Francisco y la respuesta te sirvió, puedes marcarla como aceptada (sería haciendo clic en la tilde a la izquierda de la respuesta). Esto recompensará a ambos c: